# Is the python subprocess blocking the IO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, cherrypy

I am using CherryPy as a web server, after my web server request, it may run a long long process. I don't want the web server busy on handling the process, so I separate the execution on in a separate script, and using a subprocess to call this script. But it seems that the 'subprocess' will wait the process finish. Can I do something that after the computer called the subprocess, it executed in the background on it own? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about what your problem is, and possibly provide an example?

Comment: Please show us [MCVE].

Comment: `subprocess` is a module, there are many resources in that module some that will [wait for the subprocess to finish before continuing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and others that [will be asynchronous.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)